# MongoDB Slow Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm running a mongoDB query and it's taking too long. I'm querying the collection "play_sessions" for the data of 9 users as seen in (1). My documents contain data for a gameplay session for a user as seen (2). I have an index on "user_id" and this index is being used as seen in the .explain() output in (3). My indexes in the .stats() output are shown in (4).

The mongoDB version is 2.6.1. There are approximately 4 million entires in "play_sessions" and 43,000 distinct users.

This example query takes around 2 min and the actual query of 800 users takes a lot longer. I'd like to know why this query is slow and what I can do to speed it up.

(1) The query:

```
db.play_sessions.find({user_id: {$in: users}}, {play_data:-1}
```

(2) Example document:

```
{
    "_id" : 1903200,
    "score" : 1,
    "user_id" : 60538,
    "time" : ISODate("2014-02-12T03:49:59.919Z"),
    "level" : 1,
    "user_attempt_no" : 2,
    "game_id" : 181,
    "play_data" : [
       **Some JSON in here**
    ],
    "time_sec" : 7.989
}
```

(3) .explain() output

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_id_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 13724,
    "nscannedObjects" : 13724,
    "nscanned" : 13732,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 14128,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 14140,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 4463,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 123631,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "user_id" : [
            [
                41930,
                41930
            ], 
             ...,
            [
                67112,
                67112
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "...",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

(4) .stats() output for the collection:

```
{
    "ns" : "XXX.play_sessions",
    "count" : 3957328,
    "size" : 318453446112,
    "avgObjSize" : 80471,
    "storageSize" : 319917328096,
    "numExtents" : 169,
    "nindexes" : 10,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 1962280880,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 184205280,
        "game_id_1" : 167681584,
        "user_id_1" : 113997968,
        "user_id_1_game_id_1_level_1_time_1" : 288972544,
        "game_id_1_level_1" : 141027824,
        "game_id_1_level_1_user_id_1_time_1" : 301645344,
        "user_id_1_game_id_1_level_1" : 228674544,
        "game_id_1_level_1_user_id_1" : 245549808,
        "user_id_1_user_attempt_no_1" : 135958704,
        "user_id_1_time_1" : 154567280
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: What's the count of **users** in `db.play_sessions.find({user_id: {$in: users}}, {play_data:-1})`?

Comment: What I asked is about the array **users** in the query, not data stored in the database. If the number of elements of **users** is about 14K (according to your .explain() output), it should be slow because of too much scanning.

Comment: In the query itself there are 9 different user IDs in users.

Comment: Sorry I missed this number at the beginning of question. According to **.explain()** output, about 14K documents will be returned - the size is about 14K x 80K = 1120MB - from 300GB files, and **nYields:4463**. It's really a tough task. Perhaps sharding the collection can make some help.

Comment: I doubt that sharding the collection will be of much help. The amount of data still would have to be transferred, and this by nature is a slow process, exspecially when it has to be sorted. The scatter/gather might even worsen the situation, wouldn't it? The best bet is to reduce the data returned by using projection, especially on the playdata field.